# Bash Regex - string should not start and end with a dot

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I have a script that takes a string input from users. I am looking to check that the string input should have exactly 2 dots. The relevance is only to the dots. The string should not start and end with a dot.There should be no consecutive dots.

This is the pattern I am using:

```
^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$
```

**This is the string I am looking for**:

```
abc.def.xyz
```

But in the pattern above, if dots are in front or at the end, then that string gets selected - which I don't want. There should be only two dots in the string.

**Not wanted:**

```
.abc.xyz # no dot at the start   
abc.xyz. # no dot at the end   
abc.def.ced.xyz # only two dots not more than that
```

I have tried using `(?!\.)` for the dot at the start, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "The string should not start and end with a dot" -- do you mean it shouldn't have a dot at *either* end, or that it's ok if it has a dot at one end as long as it doesn't *also* have one at the other? Similarly, when you say it "does not filter" the examples, do you mean it doesn't match them (i.e. doesn't filter them *in*), or that it doesn't *not* match them (i.e. doesn't filter them *out*)?

Comment: I think your examples should be `abc.def.xyz`?

Comment: The solution/fix to your RE is simple enough -- remember that `*` means **zero** or more.  Change your RE to `^[^\.][^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.][^\.]*$`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not saying how the string is input from the user, but note that if it may contain newline characters, you can't  use `grep` to filter them (unless you use the `--null` extension) as `grep` works on one line at a time. Also note that the `[^\.]` regex matches on characters other than backslash and `.` and the `.` regex operator (or `[...]`) in many regex implementations will not match on bytes that don't form valid characters in the locale.

Here, to check that `$string` contains 2 and only 2 dots, but not at the start nor end and not next to each other, you can use the standard `sh`:

```
case $string in
  (*.*.*.* | .* | *. | *..* ) echo not OK;;
  (*.*.*) echo OK;;
  (*) echo not OK;;
esac
```

Or with ksh globs, a subset of which can be made available in the bash shell by doing `shopt -s extglob`:

```
case $string in
  ( +([!.]).+([!.]).+([!.]) ) echo OK;;
  (*) echo not OK;;
esac
```

`bash` can also do extended regex matching with the `=~` operator inside its `[[...]]` ksh-style construct, but again, you'll want to fix the locale to C:

```
regex_match_in_C_locale() {
  local LC_ALL=C
  [[ $1 =~ $2 ]]
}

if regex_match_in_C_locale "$string" '^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$'; then
  echo OK
else
  echo not OK
fi
```

POSIXly, you can do basic regex matching with the `expr` utility:

```
if
  LC_ALL=C expr "x$string" : 'x[^.]\{1,\}\.[^.]\{1,\}\.[^.]\{1,\}$' > /dev/null
then
  echo OK
else
  echo not OK
fi
```

Or extended regex matching with the `awk` utility:

```
regex_match_in_C_locale() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -- 'BEGIN {exit(ARGV[1] !~ ARGV[2])}' "$@"
}
if regex_match_in_C_locale "$string" '^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$'; then
  echo OK
else
  echo not OK
fi
```

Comment: I was looking to select a string like `abc.def.xyz`.This pattern helped me out  `^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$` and thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for this regex `^[^.]\+\.[^.]\+\.[^.]\+$`, in this example we will use `grep`:

The characters inside brackets are treated literally (except `-`), so you don't need to escape the dot.

```bsh
$ echo ".a.b.c." | grep  "^[^.]\+\.[^.]\+\.[^.]\+$"
$ echo ".a.b.c"  | grep  "^[^.]\+\.[^.]\+\.[^.]\+$"
$ echo "a.b.c."  | grep  "^[^.]\+\.[^.]\+\.[^.]\+$"
$ echo "a..c"    | grep  "^[^.]\+\.[^.]\+\.[^.]\+$"
$ echo "a.b.c"   | grep  "^[^.]\+\.[^.]\+\.[^.]\+$"
a.b.c
```

The regex says

- The string must start with one or more characters that are not dots, followed by a dot `^[^.]\+\.`, followed by one or more characters that are not dots and a dot `[^.]\+\.`, followed by one or more characters that are not dots `[^.]\+$` until the end of the line.

Comment: I modified your pattern a little bit `^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$` which worked for me, I don't why it worked, but thanks for guiding me with `^[^.]` and `+` instead of `^[^\.]` and `*`

Comment: @depar It depends with what tool you are using  the pattern. In this case with `grep` the `+` has to be escaped for it to work.

Comment: `\+` is a GNU extension. The standard equivalent is `\{1,\}` or use `grep -E` for extended regexps, and then `+`.

Answer (score 1):

In awk, we can do this:

```
$ awk '  $0"."  ~   /^([^.]+\.){3}$/  ' file

a.b.c
abc.def.xyz
```

Adding a **dot** at the end, makes the pattern repetitive, just three times of `not-dot` followed by a `dot`. Like **a.** -- **b.** -- **c.** or **abc.** -- **def.** -- **xyz.**

Or, in regex parlance: `([^.]\.){3}`

Only accept if the regex could match the whole line.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this in bash, this is one approach:

```bsh
IFS="." read -ra words <<<"$input"
if ((${#words[@]} == 3)) && [[ $input != .* && $input != *. ]]; then
    echo "valid input"
fi
```

This one actually use the values in the words array:

```bsh
IFS="." read -ra words <<<"$input"
# 3 dot-separated fields, and the first and last cannot be empty
if ((${#words[@]} == 3)) && [[ -n ${words[0]} && -n ${words[2]} ]]; then
    echo "valid input"
fi
```

Comment: With this `a..c` gives `valid input`, as well as `a.b.c.`, wich I understand is not what OP wants.

Comment: Oh, I think the examples given are wrong, they should be `a.b.c`, not `a.b`.

Comment: `IFS=. read -ra words` splits `a.b.c.` into `a`, `b` and `c` only in bash, so the second approach won't work.